# What metaphor can I use for a collection of notes/facts?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, metaphors

I'm trying to come up with a metaphor that represents a collection of facts/notes around one thing. I've tried "deck" and "notebook" but they don't really work. Any ideas?

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you are looking for. Can you give us a sentence in which you'd like to use the word? You might consider a *body* of knowledge.

Comment: It would be used as in "Create New [metaphor]" or "Add to [metaphor]". In the computer software sort of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to start with, to say they're *a collection* is to assume they're the same kind of thing, and that they are somehow connected, at least for future reference and retrieval. So some work has been expended to mark them.

Second, to say that they're "collected" *around* one thing is to say that there is some metaphorical geometric arrangement. Mathematically, the thing they're *around* implies a polar coordinate system, either 2- or 3-dimensional, with the "thing" centred at (0, 0(, 0)) and possibly a distance metric between the items in the collection and the center point, though not necessarily between the items themselves.

There are, of course, many more dimensions in collections like this than three.
But three is all we can deal with cognitively, so that's what metaphors use.
Take your pick:

- Two-dimensional **Surface** (*on/onto, page, paper, letter*, **written**) metaphors
- Three-dimensional **Container** (*in/into/within, contain/contents*, **conceptual**) metaphors

*Deck* has several meanings, and I'm assuming it's the *deck of cards* sense you intend. That makes it a collection of 2-dimensional objects, which is OK, but without any center or connections, beyond four suits, two colors, ten digits (from *2* through *10* rather than 0 through 9), four capital letters (A, J, Q, K), and a slew of rules for playing with them.

You **could** also be referring to a *Tarot deck*, but that's just too obscure (though the category space is much much larger in Tarot, there aren't nearly as many games). And two-dimensional metaphors are most useful for writing, and there's damn little on either *deck*. So I can imagine that didn't work well.

As for *notebook*, there are way too many things that are called *notebooks*. You don't want a piece of all-purpose hardware, but that's the first thing that pops up these days when one hears *a notebook*. The original, pen-and-ink, variety is another collection of two-dimensional objects, this time with writing on them, which is an improvement, but linked only at one edge, with no centroid, no metric, no categorization, no interrelations -- and no index, a fatal flaw. So that's not surprising, either.

You might try some 3-D metaphors: *database, box, sack/bag, shelf/ves, cabinet*, etc.

However, since a good metaphor should match more than abstract characteristics, one can't go much further than this without knowing more, like

- What kind of thing are the "things"?

  - Are the "things" real, physical, discrete objects? Events? States? How are they measured?
  - Are the "things" -- instead -- metaphorical concepts like patterns, expectations, or beliefs?
  - If so, what metaphors are already used in their descriptions?
- What kind of thing are the "facts/notes"?

  - ditto.

Comment: On looking again, maybe the best metaphor (though it will be comprehensible only in a small group) is _hash table_. In its original sense, though _hashtags_ tend to work like this, too, and that's a potential hook. Note that _table_ is a 2½-dimensional metaphor -- it's a 2-D area with  limited vertical extension and limited vertical movement enabled. Rather like human beings, in fact.

Comment: Hmm... I dunno about that. It shouldn't be extremely technical, I'm just looking for a simple metaphor, like "Trash" or "Folder" that one could immediately understand it's purpose.

Comment: Trust me, "Trash" and "Folder" were **not** immediately understandable when they first appeared in IT. I was there and I was doing a lot of tech support. The idea that you have to "empty trash" is still a bit of a problem for some folks. You grew up with them; but very few metaphors are obvious. How about a _"hash table"_ not as a matrix, but as a large table with some "thing" on it, plus -- scattered all around the table, in movable piles or drifts or neat stacks, where you can put your finger on them right away -- all the hashtags you've accumulated, each pointing to `Whatever`.

Comment: I dunno, this metaphor is intended for a project/product, and I don't really think most people recognize what a "new hash table" button does. Collection is fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

One metaphor that comes to mind is [shoebox](http://rapgenius.com/Frank-ocean-day-away-lyrics#note-256545) - the informal/makeshift version of a **filing cabinet**. [Here's](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SNh7SyciWPMC&pg=PR11&dq=%22put%20it%20in%20the%20shoebox%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=O0aiUbbtG-an0AWlnICQCQ&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22put%20it%20in%20the%20shoebox%22&f=false) an example where the container may or may not be an *actual* "shoebox"...

> In the course of my research, whenever I ran across the name of a coworker of Tycho Brahe, I made a notecard and put it in the shoebox.

More literally, the CIA call theirs a [factbook](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/docs/notesanddefs.html).

Comment: One of the first and most useful pieces of software designed by the SIL for field linguists was called _Shoebox_, because they used to use index cards arranged in shoeboxes for field analysis. It's still supported and still available, and still free. http://www-01.sil.org/computing/shoebox/

Comment: @John: As with the link in my answer, that software context emphasises the "organised" nature of information/mementos kept in real or figurative shoeboxes, but personally I tend to associate it more with a *disorganised* collection of stuff you think/know you might want later. One thing's for sure though - in most of these written instances of [took out the shoebox](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22took+out+the+shoebox%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), regardless of whether it's a real shoebox, it certainly won't contain ***shoes***.