# "On a page" or "in a page" for a web page

Tags: grammar, prepositions, word-usage

Which is the correct usage:

> Something **on** a page

OR

> Something **in** a page

By **page**, I mean a web page, not a physical book page.

Comment: This comes up a lot: here's [one answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/71574/15299), and [another one](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/132122/15299), and [still another](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/115016/15299), all about preposition usage -- it's a metaphor issue, not a grammatical one.

Comment: It does depend on whether you mean the page you see or its HTML source code. It also depends on what the something is. Text and images are generally *on* pages. Holes and the like can be *in*. So if you put up an image of a hole you can say either. Context and examples are always welcome.

Comment: "Holes"? As in those made by bookworms?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Either is (or even *both are*) correct, but the preposition changes the meaning.

John Lawler's answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/132122/15299) goes some way to explaining the difference: the choice of preposition distinguishes between the surface and the container.

If you are treating the web page as similar to a book page — a fairly transparent metaphor — then one would use ***on*** because you are referring to something printed/written on the surface of the page. It's unlikely that you are referring to something in the physical structure of the page.

> It's on page 474 of this book.
>   It's on the front page of the website.

However, because **web** pages are usually built from structured code, it's quite easy to find something in the physical structure of the page. In this case, you're not concerned about what appears on the screen ( = the surface of the page), you're concerned with **how** the screen appears how it does. This **could** be applied to a book page, but it's less likely that something will happen within the actual paper.

> There's malicious code in that page.
>   I found a spider squashed in the page of the book.

Answer (score 22):

If you are talking about something that you are able to view on a page, you will use "ON".
If you are talking about something in its code, you will use "IN".