# To show ON or to show IN

Tags: prepositional-phrases

In scientific writing, should one say (write) "Results are shown ON Table X" or "Results are shown IN Table X"?

Answer (score 1):

in

See [ozdic.com](http://ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/table):

PREP.
in a/the ~
He showed the price fluctuations in a statistical table. United are second in the table.

Comment: Is this ('show IN') the only correct usage, or can 'show ON' also be correctly used?

Comment: Hi @Kika, no, only in is correct.

Comment: @KikaMelo Something can be *on* a table if you are referring to furniture (which means the expression occurs and will be found if you search online), but *on* doesn't refer to data which a table-layout contains. [Related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172032/on-a-page-or-in-a-page-for-a-web-page)